# Unable to connect to Heroku Postgres from Play 2.3

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, heroku-postgres

I have a Play 2.3 app in Java. For this app, I am able to connect to local Postgres server.

But I am unable to connect to Heroku Postgres server.

I have following settings in my application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://ec2test.amazonaws.com:5432/rwerwerwer"

db.default.user=eerwerwerer
db.default.password="5345fdwfdsvfvsdfsdfds"
```

I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for ho
st "172.56.17.147", user "eerwerwerer", database "rwerwerwer", SSL off
```

From PgAdim III, I am able to successful connect to Heroku database.

While adding heroku config, I got:

```
**!    No app specified.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these [steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support).

Things to remember:

1. Use Heroku commands from inside your main directory.
2. Use database connection as:

   ```
   db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
   db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
   ```
3. No need for username and password.
4. No need for Procfile.